# Eventbrite APi : Get ticket /price information for events

Tags: asp.net-web-api, eventbrite

Im using Eventbrites api to get information about events. I cant find any price information on the event, even though I can see price information if I check the events page at eventbrite site.

I can see from [here](http://eventbrite.com/developer/v3/response_formats/event/) that there is an optional property "ticket_availability", but its seems to be non-existing, even though I can see price info on the event´s eventbrite page)

Further down in the [documentation](http://eventbrite.com/developer/v3/response_formats/event/) its also mention something called "Ticket class", that should be an anonymous object, but I cant find it anywhere,

(and yes, I have contacted their dev support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Accepted answer**, cant set it until tomorrow]
Answer from eventbrite:s dev support. If you see this: THANKS!(again) :D

Ticket Classes are the object that we use to represent the prices of an event.
I think this is the endpoint you're looking for:
GET /v3/event/[EVENT ID]/ticket_classes/
https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-id-ticket-classes

That will return a list of Ticket Class objects (since events can have more than one price). Here's the documentation on the Ticket Class object it self. The `cost` field is what you are likely interested in.

Comment: please can you help me with the above cause I tried using the endpoint stated above (i.e /v3/event/[EVENT ID]/ticket_classes/) but I kept getting 404. Guess I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Didnt see this until now, however its been a ehile since I worked with this. Glad that things worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it turns out `ticket_availability` is an expansion field for the event endpoints, so you have to request it specifically.

For example, this request:

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/28582043/events/
```

Would need to become:

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/28582043/events/?expand=ticket_availability
```

This section of the documentation explains expansions: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/introduction/expansions

At the top of the documentation for Events you can see the list of expansions that are available for event endpoints: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event

`ticket_availability` doesn't contain the full data on the tickets, so using Ticket Classes as the other answer mentions is the way to go if you need a lot of information about tickets for a particular event. For example:

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/216395423537/ticket_classes/for_sale/
```